# EggCraft Build issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, ios5

We are getting this error while Build EggCraft Sample Code [(https://github.com/holgua/EggCraft).](https://github.com/holgua/EggCraft)
Is there any solution?

-Thanks in advance[image]
Error Shows as below screens shot